# Does any smooth orbifold can be triangulated by orbi-simplex(triangulation of orbifolds)

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, gn.general-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

every smooth manifold can be triangulated, is it true for orbifold?  Is it a known result? If yes, is there any reference?

reply to the comment : G does not need to  be any subgroup of Sn ,  any finite group is fine

Comment: By orbisimplex, do you mean some spaces like $\Delta^n/G$, where $G\subset S_{n+1}$ is a subgroup? Then how do you realise orbifold singularities in dimension $n$ whose isotropy group is too large to fit into $S_{n+1}$?

Comment: @Sebastian Goette, I just want a similar result with "smooth manifold has a triangulation" for orbifold setting. I dont know what the right definition of orbi simplex is, (or if there is one in the literature), perhaps G doesn't have to act on a simplex globally or maybe orbihedron fits better.

Comment: @SebastianGoette, a good example to think about is the standard triangulation (with two 2-simplices) of the sphere with three cone points.

Comment: @HJRW In that case I would suspect that one can triangulate by ordinary simplices such that each closed stratum is a subcomplex (but I know neither a proof nor a reference for that). I thought the OP wanted to have a particular structure at the orbifold points (hence, orbisimplex), maybe such that simplices are transversal to the strata.

Answer (score 9):

You have to be a bit more specific about the meaning of a "triangulation" for orbifolds. Assuming that you just want to triangulate the underlying space, the claim follows from

C. T. Yang, "The triangulability of the orbit space of a differentiable transformation group", Bull. of Amer. Math. Soc. 69 (1963), 405-408.

In order to use Yang's result, note that each smooth $n$-dimensional orbifold $O$ is the quotient of a smooth manifold $FO$ by the smooth action of $O(n)$, where $FO$ is the orthonormal frame bundle of $O$ (equipped with a Riemannian metric). If you just want a reference, you can quote Proposition 1.2.1 in

I. Moerdijk and D.A. Pronk, "Simplicial Cohomology of Orbifolds" 
Indagationes Mathematicae, Vol. 10, Issue 2 (1999) 269-293.

Comment: @haoyu: I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: ,I mean the interior of a triangulable space must be a topological manifold, right? (by the definition of triangulation), but if an orbifold can be triangulated by ordinary simplex, is the interior of any orbifold always a topological manifold?

Comment: i feel orbifold should be triangulated by orbi simplex, but the paper proves that ordinary simplex is enough. surprised

Comment: @haoyu: What is the "interior of a triangulable space"? What do you mean by "interior of an orbifold"?

Comment: @Misha, the interior of an closed domain $\Omega$ in $R^{n}$ is just all the $\Omega$ minus the boundary $\partial \Omega$ . If a triangulated space is a manifold with boundary, the interior points are just the space excluding its boundary. By the definition of "triangulation" , it is a manifold with corners.

Comment: @HaoYu: You should state more precise question: Are you now assuming that your space is a domain in $R^n$? If so, you answered your own question (about interior being a manifold). In any case, if you have more questions, you should ask them separately, not as comments to an answer.

Comment: @Misha, you misunderstand what I am saying. OK, by definition, a space that is triangulable( which is homeomorphic to a simplicial complex), must be a manifold with corner, do you agree? But any orbifold won't be a manifold with corner.

Comment: No, a triangulable space need not be a manifold with corners (just take a look at  the 1-dimensional case).

Comment: Is it true that any two triangulations are differed by a boundary of a higher dimensional simplicial complex(so we have a 'fundamental class' for closed smooth orbifold)