# Does any smooth oriented closed orbifold have a fundamental class

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, differential-topology, orbifolds, triangulations

This thread:[triangulation of orbifolds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/264060/does-any-smooth-orbifold-can-be-triangulated-by-orbi-simplextriangulation-of-or)
has shown that any smooth closed orbifold has a triangulation. My further question is: if the difference of any two triangulations $P$ and $Q$ is a boundary of a one higher dimensional simplicial complex $C$, so that $P - Q = \partial C$. If yes, we will have a canonical fundamental class for smooth closed orbifold. Thanks!